# List View Items appearing in wrong position Or are repeating

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview

HI Firstly yes this question is already asked but I have checked and tried all the answers but nothing works.

I don't know what is the case here. But I am not getting the correct Images in Listview.

here is my Adapter class

```
import java.util.List;

import com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper.UrlImageViewHelper;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdapterForNewsFeed extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<News> rowCate;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    AdapterForNewsFeed(Context context, List<News> rowCate) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowCate = rowCate;
        // NewsFeeds.newsfeedlist.setOnScrollListener(new SampleScrollListener(
        // context));

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return rowCate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return rowCate.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return rowCate.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        viewHolder1 hold = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            hold = new viewHolder1();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_list_items, null);

            convertView.setTag(hold);
        }

        else {

            hold = (viewHolder1) convertView.getTag();

            hold.feedation = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.feedactionimg);

            hold.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fullnametxt);
            hold.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
            hold.description = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.descriptiontxt);
            hold.likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likestxt);
            hold.dislikes = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.dislikestxt);
            hold.comments = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.commentstxt);
            hold.share = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sharetxt);
            hold.post = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postimg);

            final News row_pos = rowCate.get(position);

            hold.name.setText(row_pos.getfullname());
            hold.date.setText(row_pos.getposted_date());
            hold.description.setText(row_pos.getdescription());
            hold.likes.setText(row_pos.getlikeCount());
            hold.dislikes.setText(row_pos.getdislikeCount());
            hold.comments.setText(row_pos.getcommentCount());
            hold.share.setText(row_pos.getshareCount());

            //
            // if
            // (!row_pos.getphoto().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            // i.DisplayImage("http://www.risalati.com/myhubber/uploads/posts/"
            // + row_pos.getphoto(), post);
            // }
            //
            hold.feedation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onPopupButtonClick(v);

                }
            });

            if (!row_pos.getphoto().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(hold.post,
                        "http://www.risalati.com/myhubber/uploads/posts/"
                                + row_pos.getphoto());

            }
        }
        return convertView;

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onPopupButtonClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context, v);
        popUp.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popUp.getMenu());

        popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                return true;
            }
        });

        popUp.show();

    }

    class viewHolder1 {
        ImageView feedation;
        TextView name;
        TextView date;
        TextView description;
        TextView likes;
        TextView dislikes;
        TextView comments;
        TextView share;
        ImageView post;

    }

}
```

I have also tried Picasso,ImageLoader Class, LazyLoader but nothing is working.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: try keeping only single line ` hold = (viewHolder1) convertView.getTag();` in else body and move other part out of else body

Comment: @Nilesh  try this but again nothing happened :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I really don't know why it happened but just replacing this

```
     if (!row_pos.getphoto().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(hold.post,
                    "http://www.risalati.com/myhubber/uploads/posts/"
                            + row_pos.getphoto());

        }
```

with only

```
UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(hold.post,
                    "http://www.risalati.com/myhubber/uploads/posts/"
                            + row_pos.getphoto());
```

solved the problem.means just replacing the if condition does the trick.

Thanks every one for help.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine that you try to implement the `ViewHolder` pattern. Take a look to the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) reference.

The problem is that you are not implementing the pattern the right way. If the view is null you have to inflate it and take the references. If it is not null you take the object. Anyway, at the end you fill the data.

Check [this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: Sorry @Dr. Pelocho can't understand much. Can you explain what to do actually.

Comment: The ViewHolder pattern says that you only have to inflate the views once and reuse them. That's the `if (convertView == null) {inflateView()}` part. If the view is already inflated you just have to recover the `ViewHolder` object attached to them. So th pattern would be
    
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflateView()
        view.setTag(...);
    } else {
        recoverTag();
    }
    fillWithTheData();

You always have to set the image. Not only when recovering the view holder. Check this example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with the following one. May be it helps you and resolve your problem.

```
public class AdapterForNewsFeed extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<News> rowCate;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    viewHolder1 hold;

    AdapterForNewsFeed(Context context, List<News> rowCate) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowCate = rowCate;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return rowCate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return rowCate.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return rowCate.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        hold = new viewHolder1();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.feeds_list_items, null);

        hold.feedation = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedactionimg);
            hold.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fullnametxt);
            hold.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.datetxt);
            hold.description = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.descriptiontxt);
            hold.likes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likestxt);
            hold.dislikes = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.dislikestxt);
            hold.comments = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.commentstxt);
            hold.share = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sharetxt);
            hold.post = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postimg);

            convertView.setTag(hold);
        }

        else {      hold = (viewHolder1) convertView.getTag();  }



            final News row_pos = rowCate.get(position);

            hold.name.setText(row_pos.getfullname());
            hold.date.setText(row_pos.getposted_date());
            hold.description.setText(row_pos.getdescription());
            hold.likes.setText(row_pos.getlikeCount());
            hold.dislikes.setText(row_pos.getdislikeCount());
            hold.comments.setText(row_pos.getcommentCount());
            hold.share.setText(row_pos.getshareCount());


            hold.feedation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    onPopupButtonClick(v);

                }
            });

            if (!row_pos.getphoto().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {

                UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(hold.post,
                        "http://www.risalati.com/myhubber/uploads/posts/"
                                + row_pos.getphoto());

            } else {
            // Provide the Default Image
        }   
        }
        return convertView;

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onPopupButtonClick(View v) {

        PopupMenu popUp = new PopupMenu(context, v);
        popUp.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popUp.getMenu());

        popUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                return true;
            }
        });

        popUp.show();

    }

    class viewHolder1 {
        ImageView feedation;
        TextView name;
        TextView date;
        TextView description;
        TextView likes;
        TextView dislikes;
        TextView comments;
        TextView share;
        ImageView post;

    } 
}
```

Comment: Really need a headbang there :(. Tried this. but again no luck.I have previously work with listview Images dn't know what is happening this time.